# Which approach and statistical hypothesis test should I choose when testing performance results of many algorithms?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, simulation, algorithms

I have 4 algorithms which are doing the same thing in different ways. Let's name them A,B,C,D. I assume that one of them may have better results than others. I'd like to confirm this by test.

I'm going to create simulation (discrete event simulation). Results depend on 2 parameters:

- Number of update operations
- Number of search operations
  For both I can define interval between operations using random generator (normal distribution)

However I can see 2 ways here:

1. I can run few times simulation for every algorithm. In that case, tests for algorithm A and B may look different, because intervals are randomized.
2. I can generate list of exact times of operations and then run simulation for each algorithm using that list. In that case, both tests for algorithm A and B look the same.

---

Questions:

1. Is the unpaired data present in the first approach, and the paired data in the second one?
2. Which approach is better?
3. Which test should I use?  I know that that depends on distribution.